# How can I get all values returned from api? Javascript

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm trying to fetch API data and insert it in a table ( I am using VS code and live server). So far I've got the right data from the ApI and my thought is to loop that data and send it. When I try to loop the data I only get the last football match sent - Why don't I get all 13 games? I need some advice or suggestions on how to succeed.

```
    export function getMatchData() {

   return fetch('https://stryk.herokuapp.com/strycket2022')

.then(function (response) {

  return response.json();

})



.then(function (data) {


  let gameArray = data.playedGames;
  let gameInfo = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < gameArray.length; i++) {


    gameInfo = data.playedGames[i].teams[1].name + " VS " + data.playedGames[i].teams[2].name;



  }
  console.log(gameInfo);



  return gameInfo;






});
```

Comment: Move your console.log(gameInfo) line inside of the for loop and you will see all games.

Comment: @Stitt I can see the array with 13 games in the developer tool :) But for every playedGames[0-12] there is a new team on teams[1] and teams[2]. I have to give that data to a table. a new game for every row. So my problem os that even I put playedGames[i] ( which should loop thorugh all games? When I return that data after the loop - it just shows the data from playedGames[12] and not all the other..

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned,
You are setting a new value in the gameInfo variable every time, so you only see the last value
Try creating an array and pushing the value there
Here's an example:

```
  fetch('https://stryk.herokuapp.com/strycket2022')
 .then(response => response.json())
 .then(function (data) {
    const gameArray = data.playedGames;
    let gameInfo = [];

    gameArray.ForEach((game) => {
        const newGame = game.teams[1].name + " VS " + game.teams[2].name;
        gameInfo.push(newGame);

    });
    
    console.log(gameInfo);
    
    return gameInfo;
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for helping :-) I've tried this - but it gives all games in the same row and repeats 13 times. How can I make sure I will get 1 game for one row in the table? :-)

Comment: The Console.log - was just to look in developer tool :-)

Comment: Let me see how you try to draw the table

Comment: `function insertFootballGame(text) {

  for (let i = 1; i <= 13; i++) {
    let number = i; // number to show in the first td
    const tr = document.createElement('tr'); // creating tr element in the table

    // creating 2 td elements in the tr element
    let td1 = tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
    let td2 = tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));

    td1.innerText = number;
    td2.innerText = text; // takes text from the api data

    rad.appendChild(tr); // making a row in the table.
  }
}`

Comment: Check what the function gets by printing text
It seems like you sent the entire array as a string
This line td2.innerText = text inserts all the string 13 times 

Try the next comment example:

Comment: function createTable(data) {
  // Create the table element
  let table = document.createElement("table");

  // Add the table rows and cells
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    let row = table.insertRow();
    let indexCell = row.insertCell();
    let dataCell = row.insertCell();

    // Set the values for the cells
    indexCell.innerHTML = i + 1;
    dataCell.innerHTML = data[i];
  }

  // Return the table element
  return table;
}
let data = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"];
let table = createTable(data);                        document.body.appendChild(table);

Comment: I have a table in the html code like this:
  `<table id="table">
   <tr>
    <th>Rad:</th>
    <th>Lag:</th>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>X</th>
    <th>2</th>
   </tr>
  </table>`

My task is to add a tr with belonging td for each match only by using JS.  

:-)

Comment: Try instead of this line - let table = document.createElement("table");
Write let table = document.getElementById("table");

Answer (score -1):

create empty array or object instead string. i'm about variable gameInfo. and on each interation you have to add new value (gameInfo.push(value) if it will be array, for example). so you will get array that contains information about each item. you will able to use it for your goals

in your vaiant you rewriting value in gameInfo on every interation and at the end of loop you are getting only last value

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this will help to get you on the right track?

```js
fetch('https://stryk.herokuapp.com/strycket2022')
 .then(response=>response.json())
 .then(function (data) {
   let gameArray = data.playedGames;
   let gameInfo = [];
   for (let i = 0; i < gameArray.length; i++) {
     gameInfo.push( data.playedGames[i].teams[1].name + " VS " + data.playedGames[i].teams[2].name);
   }
   console.log(gameInfo.join("\n"));
});
```

Or, even shorter:

```js
fetch('https://stryk.herokuapp.com/strycket2022')
 .then(r=>r.json())
 .then(dat=>console.log(dat.playedGames.map(g=>g.teams[1].name+" vs "+g.teams[2].name).join("\n")));
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const res = await fetch('https://stryk.herokuapp.com/strycket2022')
const data = await res.json();

let gameArray = data.playedGames;
let gameInfo = [];

gameArray.map(game => {
gameInfo.push( game.teams[1].name + " VS " + game.teams[2].name);   
})

console.log(gameInfo);
```